# Java Class Cast Exception thrown even though the cast-from parent class is actually an instance of the cast-to subclass

Tags: java, android, classcastexception

I'm trying to cast a returned Thread object from Java's ThreadFactory.newThread(Runnable r) to a specific subclass of Thread which my Android application uses, as follows:

```
private ThreadFactory mvThreadSource = Executors.defaultThreadFactory();

...

//Invokes the thread factory's newThread(Runnable r) method 
//mvThreadsVector is an ArrayList<BackgroundThread>
//class BackgroundThread extends Thread and implements an interface
public void spawnBGThreads(int numThreads){
 for (int i=0;i<numThreads;i++){
  mvThreadsVector.add((BackgroundThread) mvThreadSource.newThread(new
  BackgroundThread())); 
 }
}
```

This throws a class cast exception, but I'm not sure why; I know I'm seemingly attempting to downcast which can't be done, but the Thread returned by mvThreadSource.newThread(new BackgroundThread()) should actually be an instance of BackgroundThread.  To my understanding this should make it legal to 'downcast' as I attempt to above (because it shouldn't really be downcasting), but the Android runtime (targeting SDK revision 17) disagrees.  What is illegal about the above cast?  What alternative approach should I use (hopefully short of creating my own BackgroundThreadFactory class that extends ThreadFactory)?

Comment: What does `mvThreadSource.newThread()` do? (What's the implementation of `ThreadFactory`?) Without that information, it's impossible to answer your question.

Comment: Look at it like this: A banana is a fruit, but a fruit is not a banana.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry, I forgot to include the ThreadFactory implementation; for the moment I'm just using the default Executors.defaultThreadFactory()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but the Thread returned by mvThreadSource.newThread(new BackgroundThread()) should actually be an instance of BackgroundThread

What makes you think that?

What makes you think it's a good idea to pass in an instance of `Thread` to `ThreadFactory.newThread` in the first place? In some cases, creating `Thread` instances without starting them can actually lead to memory leaks, I believe. (Quite possibly not on Android, mind you.)

There's a reason why the parameter for [`ThreadFactory.newThread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html#newThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) is of type `Runnable` instead of `Thread` - it's only *meant* to be "the action that should be run" rather than a thread. It's the `ThreadFactory`'s job to create the thread to run the action - that's why it's called `ThreadFactory` :)

You *could* create your own `ThreadFactory` which created `BackgroundThread` instances, but it's not clear why you want to do so in the first place. What's your actual requirement here? Perhaps you should actually not be building a `List<BackgroundThread>` but instead `List<BackgroundRunnable>` where `BackgroundRunnable` is an interface which extends `Runnable` and has whatever extra methods you want on it...

Comment: hmm... I see.  The use case here is basically just that I need to be able to generate BackgroundThread instances on-the-fly.  If I were to instantiate the BackgroundThread objects manually, say via mvThreadsVector.add(new BackgroundThread()), how/when would BackgroundThread's run() method be invoked?  Would I need to call it manually in that case?  Oh well, evidently I need to read up on ThreadFactory, Thread, and Runnable

Comment: @CCJ: You'd call `start()`, and the thread would start. Yes, it does sound like it would be a good idea to read up further :) (Why do you need to have threads which are instances of `BackgroundThread`? What's so special about `BackgroundThread`?)

Comment: well BackgroundThread is a rather large class I inherited from my company's contract firm's codebase... It was fine as a subclass of Thread that was instantiated and started manually, but now I need to do some more computationally intensive processing and many background threads running concurrently became desirable.  I thought that ThreadFactory would be a simple answer, but I misunderstood how ThreadFactory works behind the scenes... I'm currently looking into @RussellZahniser's suggestion below

Comment: @CCJ: Why don't you just create multiple instances of `BackgroundThread` directly then?

Answer (score 4):

`ThreadFactory` wraps a thread around a `Runnable`. So, it is creating some other kind of `Thread` that will call the `run()` method of your `BackgroundThread` when it starts.

Probably what you want to do is to create your own `ThreadFactory` implementation that creates `BackgroundThread`s.

Answer (score 2):

No, ThreadFactory.newThread returns a Thread:

```
class SimpleThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        return new Thread(r);
    }
}
```

A Thread, as returned by newThread, is not a BackGroundThread --> ClassCastException in your code.

Note that the newThread's input parameter takes a Runnable. Your BackGroundThread is a Runnable, but newThread is not meant to accept Threads. It should accept Runnables that will be wrapped into a Thread.